# QGIS field-calculator: set attributes to 1 if country name is in a list of values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

In a country table, I create a region field, ECOWAS, with 1 if the country belongs to the regions 'ECOWAS', 0 else.
Country names are in the field "sovereignt".
How can I build a field-calculator expression, in which I would list countries belonging to this region?
I tried:

```
 "sovereignt" in ('Benin',  'Burkina Faso', 'Cape Verde',  'Gambia',  'Ghana')
```

which returned the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting COMMA or ')'
```

What is a correct expression?

Comment: Which QGIS version is this? That expression works OK for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
CASE
    WHEN "sovereignt" IN ('Benin',  'Burkina Faso', 'Cape Verde',  'Gambia', 'Ghana') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```